# Can keep be used as a replacement for store?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

One of google's definitions for keep is:

> put or store in a regular place.
>
> "the stand where her umbrella was kept"
>
> synonyms:  store, house, stow, keep a place for, put away, place, put, deposit, stack, pile
> "the stand where her umbrella was kept"

To me, the example and some of the synonyms don't quite work together. My question is can keep be used in place of store in this sentence: 'I stored my wallet in my pocket.' Would the sentence be correct if I wrote 'I kept the wallet in my pocket.' (The scenario is that the wallet is already out of my pocket and I'm putting it away in my pocket.)?

Comment: This is a question for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) *as well as* you taking the trouble to consult some dictionaries.

Comment: I am English, I'm not learning :D It's just a load of my friends had been using the word in this sense, so I was wondering if I'd missed something

Comment: In 'British English' at least, 'store' has an almost obligatory entailment that there is medium- to long-term storage involved, with non-immediate access. You wouldn't say 'I stored my umbrella in the holder next to the hall-stand' or 'I usually stored my wallet in my inside jacket pocket'. Interchangeability occurs with say 'We stored/kept the kerosene in an outhouse'. Synonyms are rarely if ever totally interchangeable; the overlap here is moderate. / 'Store' in the sense of 'put / place' is again far from fully interchangeable; 'I put my wallet back in my pocket' is the idiomatic choice.

Comment: Okay, than the matter becomes *[please indicate the research have you done](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed/5043#5043)*

Comment: I found very few references on google saying it could be used that way, but my friends were so adamant that it could be used like that so I wanted to check  sorry if that's not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "kept" makes it sound like the wallet was already there. You'd be better off with a verb like "stored" or "put" which suggest that the wallet is in the process of being tucked away.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought, but quite a few of my friends had kept using it in that way 